# Jquery click method only works once in my Quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple quiz (in a style of one question at a time), this is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var item1 = document.getElementById('questionarea');
    var item2 = document.getElementById('answers');  
    var totalQuestions = $('.questionarea').size();
    var currentQuestion = 0;

    $questions = $('.questionarea');
    $questions.hide();

    $(".btn-lg").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".progress").show();
        $(".answers").show();
        $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
    });

    $('.answers').click(function() {
        $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function () {
            currentQuestion += 1;
            $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

And it works but only once! for the first question/answers. When I click on any of the button answers from the second question, nothing happens! It doesn't fade out and the third question never appears. What's the matter? Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center" id="start">Start quiz</button></div>

<!-- QUIZ AREA -->

<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 1 -->   
  <div class="questionarea QA1 text-center">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question1">Q1: How did you and your BFF meet?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="row divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> At work </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="row divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Living together</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="row divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Under unusual circumstances</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="row divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4"> In school</label></div></div>
  </div>  

<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 2 -->  
  <div class="questionarea QA2 text-center">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question1">Q2: How would you describe your friendship?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
    <div class="answers">
    <div id="row divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Needy </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="row divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Amazing</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="row divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Deep</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="row divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4"> Family</label></div></div>

</div>

<!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 3 -->  
  <div class="questionarea QA3 text-center">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question1">Q3: What do you do together?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="row divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Business </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="row divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Go out</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="row divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Just hold each other</label>         </div> 
<br>
    <div id="row divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4"> Play pranks on each other</label></div></div>  

    </div>

 <!-- QUESTION & ANSWERS 4 -->        
   <div class="questionarea QA4 text-center">
    <ul class="col-lg-6 list-group text-center">
      <p class="list-group-item question1">Q4: How often do you fight?</p>
       </ul> 
<br>
   <div class="answers">
    <div id="row divoption1">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Not much, but when we do, it's a big deal </label></div>
<br>
    <div id="row divoption2">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> We have lots of harmless tiffs</label></div> 
<br>
    <div id="row divoption3"><label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Sometimes</label>         </div> 
<br>
    <div id="row divoption4">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4"> Play pranks on each other</label></div></div>    

  </div> 
<!-- ---- -->   

</div>   
</body>
```

Comment: We need to see your HTML to help you. At a guess you may need to use delegated event handlers. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: you must have some error with currentQuestion incrementation

Comment: thanks for your answers guys! Sorry I thought this was a JS problem so I only included that, but gonna post my html too in my original post now! no errors in the console

Comment: To get a jQuery object instead of a DOM object with a few less characters `$($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn();` can be replaced with `$questions.eq(currentQuestion).fadeIn();`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that! still having the same problem tho

Comment: All of the radio buttons have the same name. You should give each answer group it's own unique name to share. When radio buttons share a common name they have a behavior of allowing only one of the group to be selected. As you have them now, you can only have one radio selected at a time. Change the names of each group of answers instead.

Comment: thanks for your help! however if I change the name "answers" for all my buttons then click() will never work, not even once! as I'm writing $(document).on("click", '.answers', function(){}  should I write something else there instead as well? I tried changing other classes/names (like name="option1" to option2,3,4 etc.) but nothing works. i'm getting kinda desperate :(

Comment: No "answers" is fine, it's `name="options"` and `id="option*"` For each group of "answers", change the `name="options"` all to `name="opt1"`. Then on the second group of "answers", change all of them to `name="opt2"`. Btw, all ids **MUST** be unique. You have a group of 4 `id="option1"`..etc. You also have duplicates of `id="row...`. I think you need `class="row"`. In the first 2 lines of JS/jQ you have `getElementById()` but the two elements `.answers` and `.questionarea` are classes not ids.

Comment: Thank you!! It's working thank god!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a JSFiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/xr9d5rg1/ (if you can do it yourself the next time, would be very helpful :D )

There was something funky going on, I updated a couple things on the code:

1 - Updated `.size()` to `.length`, as it's been updated in the last jQuery version (ignore it if you're use a older jQuery version)

2 - Updated the click reference, from `$('.answers')` to `$('.answers input')`, so it doesn't accept clicks outside of radio boxes;

3 - Updated the reference to the question, such as the user 1252748 suggested;

It seems to be working properly now; Maybe there was some weird event trigger going on, that called the increment twice;

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer resolves the problem proposed, please mark it as the `right` answer :)

Comment: I don't know how to mark it as the right answer, I ticked it and now the tick is green so I suppose that is it? Or should I do something else? sorry I'm new to the site haha. I have another problem now with the quiz (yeah...) so I'm gonna ask a new question!

Comment: Yeah, it's marked as the right answer now :), thanks. By marking as the right answer and upvoting it, you are giving credit (points) to the person who answered; that's important to encourage people to answer questions :D